# Twice left joins

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

```
TBL USERS
    user_id
    user_name

TBL MESSAGES
    message_id
    message_from_id
    message_to_id
    message_text
```

I use a simple JOIN to retrieve variables

```
SELECT *
FROM messages
LEFT JOIN users ON user_id = msg_to
WHERE msg_id = $msg_id

$user_name = $row['user_name'];
$message_text = $row['message_text'];
```

How to obtain 2 variable from same table?

```
$message_from = $row['user_name'];
$message_to = $row['user_name'];
```

I expect a result like this:

```
MSG ID     FROM     TO     TEXT
1          Paul     Mark   Blah
```

Comment: Just join to the USERS table again. Also, instead of *, specify the exact column names and give them aliases.

Comment: Thanks for helping Bob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT message_text, 
   to_users.user_name as to_user, 
   from_users.user_name as from_user
FROM messages
LEFT JOIN users as to_users ON user_id = message_to_id
LEFT JOIN users as from_users ON user_id = message_from_id
WHERE message_id = $msg_id;

$message_from = $row['from_user'];
$message_to = $row['to_user'];
$message_text = $row['message_text'];
```

Tangentially, I'd recommend that you get into the habit of using prepared statements if you're using PHP, instead of using variables in your strings like `$msg_id`. This can help protect you from SQL-Injection attacks.